# symfony2 mais de um security voter para um bundle

Tags: php, symfony-2

estou tendo problemas em criar mais de um voter para cada classe

a ideia é ter um voter para cada classe para poder realizar a segurança de acesso a mesma, o primeiro voter funcionou mas o segundo sempre da acesso negado

notei também que no `services.yml` só é possivel adicionar um só, seria possivel criar mais de um voter para um bundle?

exemplo:

```
security.access.post_voter:
        class:      AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\StateVoter
        public:     false
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }

security.access.post_voter:
        class:      AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\CityVoter
        public:     false
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
```

ele não deixa repetir o `security.acess.post_voter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o problema era porque não precisa ser chamado de post_voter, me enganei no tutorial

```
security.access.state_voter:
        class:      AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\StateVoter
        public:     false
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }

security.access.city_voter:
        class:      AppBundle\Security\Authorization\Voter\CityVoter
        public:     false
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
```

tudo certo agora